# How outdated is “HTTP: The Definitive Guide”?

Tags: http, web

I’m considering buying *HTTP: The Definitive Guide* with the goal of properly understanding HTTP and related technologies. I’m wondering if—13 years after its publication—the book is still worth buying.

To help me make a decision, I’m looking for input on two questions:

1. What important changes have happened in the world of HTTP that the book doesn’t cover? (For bonus points: what resources are recommended reading to catch up?)
2. Are any of the sections not relevant anymore at all?

Check the book’s [table of contents](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565925090.do) to get an idea of what’s covered.

Edit: This book isn’t about web fronted technologies. Obviously, there have been dramatic changes in that area since 2002. Please answer with respect to HT**TP**. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

HTTP 1.1 has been around since the late 90s. The information should still be very relevant.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/History.html

HTTP 2.0 is starting to gain momentum. It has been majorly revised and is a binary protocol now. But there are probably not many books written about it at this time.

Comment: Good point. It’s probably a good idea to educate oneself about HTTP/2. However, as of October 2015 “HTTP/2 is used by 1.9% of all the websites.” according to [this source](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/ce-http2/all/all).

Comment: Four years later, HTTP/2 adoption is now above 40%. The same question lead me here, and I am now also looking for good books on HTTP/2 (and HTTP/3 ?!) in addition to the classic book.